# How would I implement a mega menu in Orchard CMS?

Tags: menu, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, megamenu

I'm familiar with how to make normal hierarchical menus in Orchard, but I'm having some trouble formatting the menu into a mega-menu. Is there a module or advice that I can use?

Comment: What trouble? Code? Did you look up mega-menus on google for material?

Answer (score 1):

Bindtuning orchard themes implement mega menus. you can look into the trial theme, how it is done. 
http://www.bindtuning.com/cms/orchard/orchard-1/theme/SPC